# How can I get more intel while scanning at HQ?

Tags: xcom-2

I'm trying to expand into another region to stop the avatar project, but after a spending spree in the black market I have 20 intel left, not enough to expand!

I've tried sitting at the HQ and scanning, but I don't get any more intel.

How can I get more, quick (1 block left in avatar project!)

Comment: also keep in mind that if in a bordering region you have a radio tower relay, the intel cost to make contact is greatly reduced

Comment: Thanks for the tip; might actually have enough time to build one now!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to gain Intel you can scan at your HQ, but you must ensure that you have the 'Gain Intel' perk selected at your base.

When you arrive at your base, on the left hand side of the map marker is a fist icon, click this and then spend 25 supplies to change to the 'Gather Intel' perk, and then when scanning you will gain Intel.

The other perks I've seen so far are 'Quick Building' and 'Heal Faster'.

Comment: Ahhhh, I've had the very useful "heal faster" one there instead!